# What are the disadvantages of using magic methods? how to abbreviate them in child classes?

Tags: php, doctrine, magic-methods

I am extensively using magic methods for lots of purpose like common setters and getter, Implemented wrapper classes using __call(). Now have studied doctrine and I wondered they haven't used magic getter and setters actually they do not work if we specify in the models.

So my questions are HOW doctrine have abbreviated magic methods? and what are the disadvantages of using magic methods  specifically in ORM like docterine ?

Comment: Which question do you want answered? The one in the title ("what are the disadvantages of.."), or the one at the end of the body text ("how doctrine have done it..")?

Comment: @SDC I have two separate questions  let me  edit my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Magic code is hard to document and understand. Usually you should add
  a comment to every function and use a tool to generate a
  documentation. This will not work with magic methods.
- Magic methods do not support type hinting.
  One of the greatest advantages of using functions to set properties is that you can use type hinting. Code like this

  public function setUser(User $user){ this->user = $user }

  makes sure that the user property will allways contain a valid user object or null.
- IDEs do not support magic methods.
  Many modern PHP IDEs support auto complete. Functions and methods are recognized by a simple parser. This parser is not able to detect magic get set or call operations.

I heard that that magic methods are slower then explicit methods but I have never tested it myself.

So how do you do it without magic?
I use templates to generate geters and setters and usually I do not use __call at all.

Magic methods are very usefull tools for creating proxy objects and and other specialized tools but you SHOULD NOT use them in every class

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer, Do you know how to force the derived classes to not use the magic methods?

Comment: magic methods are only called when the defined method or property does not exist so if you implement all required methods there will be no magic.